# How to solve this trigonometric equation?...

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the value of x?

$$\tan x=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{(2(3\pi/4)^2-x^2)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

One solution is obvious.  There are two others that are not quite obvious.  Hint: both sides are rational numbers.